# Dryer lint trap doesnt fit

Tags: dryer

The dryer lint trap quit fitting. We cant put it back in as if it is too big. Have looked and doesn't appear to be anything blocking it and lint trap is cleaned after each use

Comment: So what's the question?  How about a few pictures so we can see what you see.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Same thing happened with me.

Answer (score 1):

Most lint filters on dryers have some type of gasket to reduce air bypassing the screen. There may be a gasket on the removable filter itself or there may be one incorporated into the filter receptacle/slot. I have seen these gaskets come unglued and bent/crumple into the slot that the filter goes into. Check for obstructions.

Comment: There is no gasket and doesn’t appear to be an obstruction.  The lint trap is a solid plastic